# jQuery hide function does not work for AJAX-generated divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am creating a small web site and I want to have a function to delete a member. I am deleting the member using an AJAX call. I want to remove the `div` of the deleted member from the page. I wrote a small function to do that.

```
function P_delete_member(id) {
    alertify.defaults.glossary.title = "Lecturer Request";
    alertify.defaults.glossary.ok = "Yes";
    alertify.defaults.glossary.cancel = "No";
    alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/seppro/index.php/P_search_controller/P_delete_member',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#member"+id).hide(500);
            },
            error: function (err, req) {
                alert("Your browser broke!");
            }
        });
        alertify.success("done");
    },
    function () {
        alertify.error('Cancel');
    });
}
```

This function works fine. But when I try to search a member and then delete, the `$("#member"+id).hide(500);` part does not work. Search results are generated from the AJAX function. How can I use `$("#member"+id).hide(500);` for AJAX-generated `div`s?

Comment: If i understood your correctly, you need to bind using on(), old live() function of jquery. You need it for elements thst are added after DOM was loaded

Comment: can you explain me how to do that

Comment: Read jquery documentation for .on()

Comment: how can i add  .on() for hide or show i dont get that

Comment: you need to reference a higher level selector such as "body" which is added to the DOM on page load, rather than the content that was added to the DOM by AJAX and so was no there initially.

Also since you are passing an ID to another page to presumably delete the member with that Id, why not return the updated list of people / content to the page rather than simply "hiding" the content?

Comment: If you `console.log` the `id` and `$("#member"+id)` on the `success` function, what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

[$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) - is an async by default. So you can't send variables from closure function to it. You have to use response data.

For exemple:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/seppro/index.php/P_search_controller/P_delete_member',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json'
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      success: function (resp) {
        $("#member" + resp.id).hide(500);
      }
});
```